# Volume differential equation (dV) in parabolic coordinate system $(\alpha, \beta, \phi)$

Tags: calculus

Having the following transformation functions:

$x = \alpha\beta cos\phi$

$y = \alpha\beta sin\phi$

$z = \frac{\beta^{2}-\alpha^{2}}{2}$

How could I obtain dV? That is the differential equation for volume's differential.

I am not get used to parabolic coordinates and I am struggling to even get started.

Comment: This site may be of use: https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/p/p055.htm

Comment: Do you know the Jacobian?

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ parabolic space. Consider vectors $\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3$ as if they were emanating from $p$. Now consider the following transformation to Euclidean space

$$(\alpha, \beta, \phi) \mapsto \left(\alpha\beta\cos\phi, \alpha\beta\sin\phi, \frac{\alpha^2 - \beta^2}{2}\right) = (x,y,z)$$

The *derivative* of the transformation at $p$ simply describes how each vector(which represents a change in position) $\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3$ is mapped as if the transformation was linear at that point. Thus, it can be described the following matrix:

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \beta} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \phi} \\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \beta} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}\\
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial \beta} & \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial \phi} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the transformation scales volumes as such: "$dV = dxdydz = \det(J)d\alpha d\beta d\phi$."

Now, we need to find $\det(J)$.

$$
\det(J) = 
\begin{vmatrix}
\beta \cos \phi& \alpha \cos \phi & -\alpha \beta \sin \phi \\
\beta \sin \phi & \alpha \sin \phi & \alpha \beta \cos \phi \\
\alpha & -\beta & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

For the sake of simplicity, expand the determinant along the bottom row.

$$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
\beta \cos \phi& \alpha \cos \phi & -\alpha \beta \sin \phi \\
\beta \sin \phi & \alpha \sin \phi & \alpha \beta \cos \phi \\
\alpha & -\beta & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
= \alpha
\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha \cos \phi & -\alpha \beta & \sin \phi \\
\alpha \sin \phi & \alpha \beta & \cos \phi \\
\end{vmatrix}
+\beta
\begin{vmatrix}
\beta \cos \phi & -\alpha \beta \sin \phi \\
\beta \sin \phi & \alpha \beta \cos \phi \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
which becomes
$$\alpha\beta(\alpha^2 + \beta^2)$$
Thus,
$$dV = \alpha\beta(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) d\alpha d\beta d\phi$$

Comment: Thank you! Would not it be $(\alpha, \beta, \phi) \mapsto \left(\alpha\beta\cos\phi, \alpha\beta\sin\phi, \frac{\beta^2 - \alpha^2}{2}\right) = (x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: That's what you put, but it is a small matter. I prefer the $z$ axis flipped so that the determinant loses the $-$ sign.